# Вопрос по C# OpenQA.Selenium

Tags: c#

Как собрать все значение `data-url="/af54359643"` используя OpenQA.Selenium ?
Пытаюсь разобраться в документации, там есть метод FindElements, но судя по всему, он значения атрибутов пачкой не спарсит(

```
<div id="naidetsya">
<ul class="kakoita tam est">
<li class="kucha vsyakih raznih" data-name="писанина всегда разная" data-url="/af54359643" data-status="true"></li>
<li class="kucha vsyakih raznih" data-name="писанина всегда разная" data-url="/qw543532643" data-status="true"></li>
<li class="kucha vsyakih raznih" data-name="писанина всегда разная" data-url="/ge5435234643" data-status="true"></li>
<li class="kucha vsyakih raznih" data-name="писанина всегда разная" data-url="/ffw54312443" data-status="true"></li>
<li class="kucha vsyakih raznih" data-name="писанина всегда разная" data-url="/adf514643" data-status="true"></li>
<li class="kucha vsyakih raznih" data-name="писанина всегда разная" data-url="/qd54124643" data-status="true"></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как спарсить все значения одной пачкой я не знаю.

Но вот следующий код должен решить задачу (накидал по памяти, но должно все работать):

```
    using (IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver())
    {
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("your_url");

        List<string> items = new List<string>();

        List<IWebElement> elements = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//div[@id='naidetsya']/ul/li")).ToList();

        foreach (IWebElement element in elements)
        {
            string item = element.GetAttribute("data-url");

            items.Add(item);
        }
    }
```

Основная мысль в том чтобы найти какой то элемент от которого можно добраться посредством Xpath до нужного тебе атрибута.

Comment: var items = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//div[@id='naidetsya']/ul/li")).Select(e => e.GetAttribute("data-url")).ToList();